# Kafka Python Producer Issues

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am running Kafka on my EC2 instance - when I spin up my bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic fake-topic --bootstrap-server {Put the Public IP of your EC2 Instance:9092} and my bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic fake-topic --bootstrap-server {Put the Public IP of your EC2 Instance:9092} I can produce to my consumer just fine and can see the messages.

When I try to produce to the topic and see messages with my bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh using a python script the messages are not visible - but I do not receive and error. When I run my script (below) I get the message "Message sent successfully" but cannot see my message in bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh. Also I tried running the code on my local machine and on the same EC2 running the Kafka broker - same result for both. I have opened the security group for port 9092 and for my homes IP address. Have added the EC2's public IP to advertised.listeners too in the config file.

```py
import pandas as pd
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from time import sleep
from json import dumps
import json

try:
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['<My-EC2-public-IP>:9092'], # Change IP here
                             value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

    producer.send('demo_test', value={'surname': 'parameter'})

    # Optionally, you can wait for the message to be sent
    producer.flush()
    print("Message sent successfully")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
finally:
    producer.close()  # Close the producer to release resources
```

Thank you in advance :)

Have explained all in my details section

Comment: what happens if you print the result (partition, offset) of the future from the `produce.send`? (`result = future.get(timeout=10)`)

Comment: Can you please show more debug steps? What happened when you leave the console consumer running **then** run the Python/CLI producer? What happens when use `--from-beginning`? Or Offsetshell to check offsets actually updated? Do you need to use EC2 instead of MSK, for example? If it didn't work locally, the VPC isn't the immediate issue